# Managing Scheduled Tasks in a Clustered Environment

Tags: architecture, scheduled-tasks, cluster-computing

I have a small cluster of servers that are used for handling a fair amount of web traffic. It's a pretty standard setup; 3 web servers, load balancer, database server, warehouse server.

The difficulty is that I have a number of different tasks that run on a scheduled basis, and those tasks vary drastically with respect to how often they run. The items are:

1. Warehouse jobs. Obviously running on the single warehouse server. Might be a problem in the future, but for now we only have one warehouse. Runs nightly.
2. Scheduled reports. Using Quartz.NET, fired in our ASP.NET environment. Runs whenever the users schedule them, typically daily.
3. Stats snapshots. Running in ASP.NET via a thread fired up with the app pool, takes a snapshot of the overall system load for future analysis. Runs every 2 minutes.
4. System events. We have lots of "stuff" in the system that need to change their status on a relatively high frequency (on any given check, ~5-10 items will need a status update) and broadcast that information out to the connected web clients. Currently set to run in a thread in the app pool as well. Runs every 2 seconds or so.

All this works perfectly in a single-server setup, and even in a multi-server setup I can just turn things off on the non-primary web servers (which is my current solution).

The real question is, what's the best way to set this up so there's a little more redundancy built into the system? Extract the whole thing into windows services on a different box (boxes)? Have the web servers communicate with each other so they can detect a failure on the primary and have a secondary take over?

I'm interested in any thoughts/suggestions!

Comment: Interesting question! In terms of resource and currently load, can you explain a bit more on your current system characteristics? I mean what are your resource constraint? Can you afford some more hardware? At max load - what are the mem/proc utilization of all 3 servers. That would help to focus on providing specific suggestions.

Comment: No huge constraints on hardware. Database server sits at about 10-15% CPU, maxed out RAM (big database), web servers run about 15-30% usage on average, lower off-peak, higher during peak. Nothing crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure how it relates to the .NET world, but a clustered singleton service might be your answer.

Comment: I like the idea, if there's a corresponding .NET version...

Comment: I would recommend JGroups if this is in Java. Sample implementation can be found here at http://speakingjava.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-execute-singleton-task-in-cluster.html. Fortunately GCT (http://www.jgroups.org/success.html) is based on JGroups and is for .NET.